# Glide installing issue

Tags: docker, go, glide-golang

Installing glide is failing:

```
Step 3/17 : RUN curl https://glide.sh/get | sh
...
Step 5/17 : RUN glide install
...
/bin/sh: 1: glide: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c glide install' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

When I access `https://glide.sh/get`, I get certificate error...
Is glide still used? Shall I rewrite my Dockerfile to some newer way of installing dependencies?

Comment: Don't install Glide. It's been obsolete for years. Use Go modules.

Comment: [This article](https://blog.golang.org/migrating-to-go-modules) may be of help.

Answer (score 3):

> Is glide still used?

No.

> Shall I rewrite my Dockerfile to some newer way of installing dependencies?

Yes, of course. Use Go modules. See https://golang.org/doc/modules/managing-dependencies .